# Map through nested array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which returns these values:

```
0: {Carat: '7,02', Clarity: 'VS1', Color: 'E', Crwn angle: '34,50', Crwn depth%: '15,00', …}
1: {Carat: '5,33', Clarity: 'VS1', Color: 'G', Crwn angle: '35,80', Crwn depth%: '15,50', …}
2: {Carat: '4,52', Clarity: 'VVS2', Color: 'D', Crwn angle: '0,00', Crwn depth%: '0,00', …}
```

I am trying to map through these objects to display the properties i.e. Carat:

```
{Array.map((diamond) => (
   <div
    key={diamond.carat}
    className="relative flex flex-col overflow-hidden bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg hover:shadow-sm group"
    >
```

Unfortunately, my screen stays empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably `diamond.map(d => console.log(d.Carat))` or something along those lines...

Comment: If this is React code, then add React tag to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, if you elaborate further maybe I could help. If you just want to print out the property names and their values you could do something like this...

```js
const testObj = {
 Carat: '7,02', 
 Clarity: 'VS1', 
 Color: 'E', 
 Crwnangle: '34,50', 
 Crwndepth: '15,00'
}

const items = Object.entries(testObj);

for (item of items) {
 console.log(item);
}
```

If you post the complete JS file I'll have more context and will probably be able to produce a more useful solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should check for `diamond.Carat` or `diamond['Carat']` instead of `diamond.carat`.

Note that in your object example, all the key names start with a capital letter, but in your snippet, the 'c' is lowercase.

Always check your variable cases. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you have an array of data, like this:

```
dataArr = [
  {Carat: '7,02', Clarity: 'VS1', Color: 'E', "Crwn angle": '34,50', "Crwn depth%": '15,00'},
  {Carat: '5,33', Clarity: 'VS1', Color: 'G', "Crwn angle": '35,80', "Crwn depth%": '15,50'},
  {Carat: '4,52', Clarity: 'VVS2', Color: 'D', "Crwn angle": '0,00', "Crwn depth%": '0,00'},
];
```

You can map `Carat` to caratList:

```
const caratList = dataArr.map(({ Carat }) =>
  <li>{Carat}</li>
);
```

And render it in browser:

```
<ul>{caratList}</ul>
```